# I have an iPod Touch 5th gen. Can I play Pokemon Go?

Tags: ios, pokemon-go

Long story short, I have an iPod 5, and I've been excited for this game for about a year now. I keep getting a GPS signal not found. Can I play under wifi or some sort of cellular data?

Comment: WiFi is not a substitute for GPS.

Comment: As far as I am aware iPod 5 has no GPS receiver and no mobile internet connectivity. You could use tethering, but no GPS is a deal breaker.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can not play Pokemon GO on an iPod Touch 5G ***reliably***.

As Pokemon GO requires players and their devices to provide the game with an accurate position (which WiFi triangulation does not), you will face frequent GPS errors.

In order to pull off positioning with WiFi reliably, you need to be in a very WiFi-heavy location (at least 10-11 networks with location data assigned). These, unfortunately, are not too common unless you live in a major metropolitan area.

Comment: Wi-fi location is pretty decent, better than gps indoors generally even. Can you not use wi-fi location to play the game or does the game require a gps signal to work?

Comment: @Aequitas I'm fairly confident that Pokemon GO doesn't use WiFi location as a reliable location source, as it can be spoofed rather easily.

Comment: FWIW, iTunes lists the requirements as **Requires iOS 8.0 or later. Compatible with iPhone, iPad, and iPod touch.**

Comment: @phantom42 Niantic has been known to check all the pretty tickmarks in the past. But if someone can give me authoritative proof that PoGo works on WiFi, I'll edit my answer. (Obviously I'm not going to go out and buy an iPod just to test this)

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemongo/comments/4sthe6/my_experience_with_pokemon_go_on_ipod_touch_5g/

Answer (score 5):

You can use an iPod, I do, but you need Wifi or to be on someone's hotspot while you're out doing things. If it says "GPS Service not found" pull the screen down to where it shows stocks and things and it will update.

Answer (score 2):

You can. You'll be having trouble opening the app but you can. The only thing is that the avatar doesn't move as you do.