# Can I download GPS so I can play Pokémon go?

Tags: pokemon-go

I have an iPod 6th generation.

Comment: @Alex I did. I see nothing wrong with the question, beside a possible lack of research.

Comment: @Alex a user's reasons for voting are their own, and voting is anonymous for this reason. It might not deserve an upvoted in *your* eyes but other people are different to you. :-). It should also go without saying, but when voting yourself, do not take other votes into account. Don't 'pity upvote' or downvote because "this question doesn't *deserve* it's current score", votes are meant to denote 'good' or 'bad' content, nothing else

Comment: You wouldn't download a car

Comment: @JK01 I would if I could. I also download RAM regularly.

Answer (score 7):

GPS is not an app, it's hardware, like the speaker or microphone. Your iPod does not have this hardware.

Some users have reported [various levels of success](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/272801/i-have-an-ipod-5-can-i-play-pokemon-go) using Wi-Fi location tracking only. There is also a 'Battery Saver' mode in the settings which - amongst other things - seems to reduce the amount of location requests and thereby reduce the time the 'No GPS' message is active.

So in conclusion, you *may* have some success with your iPod, but if you want to guarantee you are able to play PoGo successfully you need to consider getting a GPS-enabled smartphone.

Answer (score 1):

No. GPS requires specific hardware which must be included in the device at the time of manufacture.

Comment: And the iPod 6 does not have this hardware?

Comment: @DCShannon Indeed, has none

Comment: @DCShannon only iPhones and iPads with Cellular have this.not sure about iPads though

Comment: No, it does not.

Comment: @SaintWacko That's a pretty incomplete answer without that fact.

Comment: The question is "Can I download GPS so I can play Pokemon go?" The answer is no, you can't download GPS, no matter what your device is. If the question were "Does my iPod 6th gen have GPS?" I would close it as off-topic.