# Why does my character jump around when playing Pokemon Go on an iPod?

Tags: ios, pokemon-go

I have a iPod touch 6th generation and in Pokemon Go it works perfectly fine but my character moves when I dont move, wanders around and pervents me from battling in gyms.

Are there any solutions to this issue?

Comment: iPod Touch? I assume Wifi only without any cellular data?
It sounds like GPS updates are not accurate enough (but not completely inaccurate as well), which makes your character move

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I have an iPod 5. Can I play Pokemon Go?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/272801/i-have-an-ipod-5-can-i-play-pokemon-go)

Comment: @NBN-Alex - related, but not the same question.

Answer (score 5):

The iPod touch does not support GPS the way it is meant to be used with Go.

> One major difference between the iPhone and the iPod touch is that the touch doesn't include true GPS features. It offers a limited kind of location awareness that is useful in many cases, but if you need true accuracy or are in a rural location, the iPod touch may leave you lost.

The reason it works funky for you is:

> If there aren't many nearby Wi-Fi networks, or none at all, the touch won't be able to figure out where it is. That means it won't be able to provide turn-by-turn driving directions, suggestions for nearby restaurants, and similar information

[Source](http://ipod.about.com/od/introductiontotheipod/f/Ipod-Touch-Gps-Options.htm)