# Pokemon GO isn't working on my iPod 5g

Tags: pokemon-go

When I open Pokemon GO all I get is a black screen and then the app closes. I have a iPod 5th gen. I've been looking forward to this game for a long time so how can I fix this?

Comment: Already answered here 
http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/272801/i-have-an-ipod-5-can-i-play-pokemon-go/272804

Answer (score 0):

The iPod 5G doesn't come with a GPS installed, so it can't play Pokémon go.